# $A$ complex, not diagonal, can $A^*A$ be diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a complex matrix which is not diagonal, can $A^*A$ be diagonal?

My first impression is that it cannot, and my mind runs to the fact that $\operatorname{Tr}{(A^* A)}\geq \sum |\lambda_i(A)|^2$ if $A$ is not normal. But of course the normality of $A$ is not necessarily relevant... any ideas?

Comment: Take any unitary $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more general than Daniel's suggestion: if $A = UP$ is a [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of $A$, then $A^*A$ is diagonal if and only if $P$ is (nonnegative) diagonal.

**Proof.** First, note that $A^*A = P^* U^* U P = P^2$.

One way is simple: if $P$ is diagonal, then $A^*A$ is diagonal.

Now, let us assume that $A^*A = P^2$ is diagonal. Since $A^*A$ is positive semidefinite, it has a unique positive semidefinite square root. Since $P$ is positive semidefinite and $P^2 = A^*A$, we see that $(A^*A)^{1/2} = P$.

Denote diagonal elements of $A^*A$ as $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$. Then

$$(A^*A)^{1/2} = \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{d_1}, \sqrt{d_2}, \dots, \sqrt{d_n})$$

is also diagonal, so $P$ must be diagonal as well.

Comment: Very nice! Just the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel has pointed out rightly that an easy example is a unitary matrix.